# Wordnet (Word Sense Annotated) Corpus

Tags: nlp, wordnet, corpus, tagged-corpus

I've been utilizing lots of different corpora for natural language processing, and I've been looking for a corpus that has been annotated with Wordnet Word Senses.

I understand that there probably is not a big corpus with this information, since the corpus needs to be built up manually, but there has to be something to go off of.

Also if there isn't a corpus in existence, is there at least a sense annotated ngram database (with what percentage of the time a word is each of its definitions, or a numerical count of each wordnet definition depending on how common the word sense is)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three prominent corpora annotated for WordNet:

- [MASC](http://americannationalcorpus.org/MASC/About.html)
- [WordNet gloss](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/glosstag.shtml)
- [SemCor](http://www.cse.unt.edu/~rada/downloads.html#semcor)

Comment: SemCor was by far the best one out of all the ones linked. Looks like there are not a lot of high quality WordNet annotated corpus' available right now.

Comment: @cardine and cyborg, sorry for the comment, but i couldn't find your contact info. could you email me at info @ panabee.com? based on your NLP interests, i have a small project you might be interested in. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the [SENSEVAL](http://www.senseval.org/) (now [SEMEVAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SemEval)) data is annotated with WordNet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use senseval2, for java there is a semcor format and (jSemcor API)
and also senseval3.
these two corpus are used for Word sense disambiguation.